# Loop and add function component as index

Tags: python, indexing

I would like to change the index of the following code. Instead of having 'close' as the index, I want to have the corresponding x from the function. As sometimes like in this example even if i provide 4 curr only 3 are available. Meaning that I cannot add the list as the index after looping as the size changes. Thank you for your help. I should add that even with the set_index(x) the index remain 'close'.

The function daily_price_historical retrieve prices from a public API . There are exactly 7 columns from which I select the the first one (close).

The function:

```
def daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, all_data=False, limit=1, aggregate=1, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    if all_data:
        url += '&allData=true'
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
    return df
```

The code:

```
curr = ['1WO', 'ABX','ADH', 'ALX']

d_price = [] 
for x in curr:
  try:
    close = daily_price_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').close
    d_price.append(close).set_index(x)
  except:
    pass
d_price = pd.concat(d_price, axis=1)
d_price = d_price.transpose()
print(d_price)
```

The output:

```
            0
close  2.6100
close  0.3360
close  0.4843
```

Comment: Sorry, 'daily_price_historical' is not running in my system, Is that predefined function or custom. (NameError: name 'daily_price_historical' is not defined)

Comment: I 've added the function. It is custom function.

Comment: This line is wrong: `d_price.append(close).set_index(x)`. If `d_price` is a list, `d_price.append(...)` returns None. Are you trying to do `d_price.append(close.rename(x))`

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you so much. You did it. It works. I don't understand exactly why. "d_price.append(close).set_index(x)" do not return None. But the index remains unchanged.

Comment: @maf: see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `daily_price_historical` returns a dataframe, so `daily_price_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').close` is a pandas `Series`. The *title* of a `Series` is its name, but you can change it with rename. So you want:

```
...
close = daily_price_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').close
d_price.append(close.rename(x))
...
```

In your original code, `d_price.append(close).set_index(x)` raised a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_index'` exception because `append` on a list returns `None` but the exception was raised after the `append` and was silently swallowed by the catchall `except: pass`.

What to remember from that: **never** use the very dangerous :

```
try:
    ...
except:
    pass
```

which hides any error.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this small code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

curr = ['1WO', 'ABX','ADH', 'ALX']
def daily_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, all_data=False, limit=1, aggregate=1, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
            .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    if all_data:
        url += '&allData=true'
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
    return df

d_price = []
lables_ind = []
for idx, x in enumerate(curr):
    try:
        close = daily_price_historical(x, 'JPY', exchange='CCCAGG').close
        d_price.append(close[0])
        lables_ind.append(x)
    except:
        pass

d_price = pd.DataFrame(d_price,columns=["0"])
d_price.index = lables_ind
print(d_price)
```

**Output**

```
          0
1WO  2.6100
ADH  0.3360
ALX  0.4843
```